# Rails 3 Route Nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

My Rails app routing looks something like this:

```
match 'Events/New' => 'event#new'
match 'Events/:date' => 'event#show', :date => /[A-Z][a-z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/
match 'Events/:date/Venue' => 'event#venue', :date => /[A-Z][a-z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/
match 'Events/:date/Speakers' => 'event#speakers', :date => /[A-Z][a-z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/
```

Is there some way to nest this and clean it up?  I suspect it's running the regex on :date multiple times, while nesting could theoretically make it run once.

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: You only have four routes. Any attempt to nest this would just make your routing table longer and add complexity.

Comment: There are many more routes.  My thought is that nesting could make routes.rb cleaner, similar to how writing CSS with LESS can clean things up. I understand that the performance improvement is probably negligible, but I still think it's worthwhile for readability.  Is there something about the Rails platform that actually makes this more expensive?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing `scope` should solve your problem!
Something like:

```
scope :module => "events" do
  // ...
end
```